# How to use spread operator to delete an object from array of objects using spread operator using react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i want to delete an object from array of objects using spread operator.

i have an array of objects like below,

```
const list= [ 
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'first_item',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'second_item',
    },
]
```

i can add another object say "next_item" like below

```
const next_item = {
    id: '3',
    name: 'next',
}


const final = [...list, next_item]
```

similary how can i delete delete_item from list

```
const delete_item = {
    id: '2',
    name: 'second_item',
},
```

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use the spread operator for this?  That's not what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no such thing with spread operator, but if you still want to force**, here you go

```js
var arrayObj = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

const index = arrayObj.findIndex(elm => elm === 5)
const removed = [...arrayObj.slice(0,index) , 
                ...arrayObj.slice(index+1,arrayObj.length)]

console.log(removed)
```

**But there is no benefit of using it like this**

---

You can use some of the **destructuring** features like this :

```js
var arrayObj = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var [first , second , ...rest ] = arrayObj;

console.log(first , second , rest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter

```
list = list.filter(item => {
return item.id !=2;
})
```

Or can use a function like the below

```
const removeFromList = (list, itemId) => {
    return list.filter(item => {
      return item.id != itemId;
    });
}
```